# Code after the if-statement block not running!

Tags: solidity, remix

In the following solidity code if the user dislike an nft it should do the following--

- If the user
  has already disliked the nft, it should revert. (it works!)
- If the
  user has already liked the nft, the code should set like-- and
  dislike++ for the given user, (the like-- works!)

**but it should also set usersDisliked to true and run the code which increments the dislikes and decrement the netlikes!**
and for some reason it isnt running!

```
 mapping(uint256 => Nft) public nftMapping;

 struct Nft {

        //A unique id for every nft in the bitverse.
        uint256 id;
        //The address of the contract the NFT is deployed.
        address tokenAddress;
        //The id of the NFT
        //NOTE: "The ownership can be found out by calling the ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) function inside the ERC721 contract"
        //The owner can change, bitverse rewards the current owner, i.e. ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId).
        uint tokenId;
        //Token Standard
        //ERC721: '721';
        //ERC1155: '1155';
        //Any new standard can be added like this.
        uint tokenStandard;
        //Total likes the NFT got.
        uint256 likes;
        //Total dislikes the NFT got.
        uint256 dislikes;
        // This is the net number of likes
        // netlikes = likes - dislikes.
        // It can also be a negative number,
        // hence a signed integer.
        // The token rewarded are calculated upon the number of netlikes.
        // Note: No tokens can be rewarded more than once for the same milestone,
        // We use milestone below to keep track of the checkpoints.
        int256 netlikes;
        // This is used to make sure no author is rewarded a token more than once for the same milestone.
        uint256 milestone;
        // This mapping contains all the users who've liked this NFT.
        // Also used to make sure no user likes the NFT more than once.
        mapping(address => bool) usersLiked;
        // This mapping contains all the users who've disliked this NFT.
        // Also used to make sure no user dislikes the NFT more than once.
        mapping(address => bool) usersDisliked;
        // The timestamp from the block when this NFT came into existence in the bitverse.
        uint256 timeStamp;
    }


    //Event emitted when someone dislikes the nft.
    event NftDisliked(uint256 nftId, address disliker, uint timeStamp);
    
    function dislikeNft(uint256 _nftId) public {
    
         Nft storage n = nftMapping[_nftId];
    
        if (n.usersDisliked[msg.sender] == true) revert alreadyDisliked();
    
        if (n.usersLiked[msg.sender] == true) {
            n.usersLiked[msg.sender] == false;
            n.likes--;
            n.netlikes--;
           
        }
    
        //looks like these lines are not running
        //how do I make sure this runs
        n.usersDisliked[msg.sender] = true;
        n.dislikes++;
        n.netlikes--;
        emit NftDisliked(_nftId, msg.sender, block.timestamp);
    
    }
```

---

**Using remix-ide.**

**with solidity compiler - 0.8.11**

**pragma solidity ^0.8.0;**

Comment: Could you define the parameter Nft in your code? It makes a difference if it's interface type, contract type, or struct.

Comment: just added the nft struct!

Comment: Odd, it should work.

Comment: it was a very stupid mistake, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I realized what it is!

It's a very stupid mistake!

that **'=='** in

```
 n.usersLiked[msg.sender] == false;
```

is supposed to be **'='**
so, the correct way would be-

```
n.usersLiked[msg.sender] = false;
```

Thank you everyone for your considerations anyway.
I might delete this question later.

Comment: That wouldn't effect the state of likes and dislikes unfortunately, which is the problem you described.

Comment: I got confused as on my frontend, both like/disliked button was up, like I said it was stupid.

Comment: Make sense, best of luck.